# jquery window width condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Later edit: 
I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ( $(window).width() > 800 ) {
    $("#header").hide();
}
else {
$("#header").show();
}

});
```

if I resize the window below 800 the header is still invisible.
What is the problem ?
I can't use css media queries because I want to execute other functions when the windows is bigger than 800.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Javascript with JQuery, you'll probably want to know a couple things: what's the width right now, and what's the width after the user resizes?  You'll probably have code that looks something like this:

```
function checkSize(){
  if ( $(window).width() > 1200 ){
    //do whatever
  }
}

//When the page is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Add a listener to check the size of the document when you load
  $(document).resize(checkSize);

  //Check the size now.
  checkSize();
});
```

Alternatively, you can use CSS Media queries to adjust the CSS when the page is a certain size, but it won't execute any Javascript.  Here's an example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #header{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

This has some more helpful examples and explanations: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Basically what I want to do is when the width is smaller than 1200 to show the header, and when is larger than 1200 to hide the header, I can't use the css media queries because I want to add also other functions

Comment: In that case, my Javascript should get you started.

Comment: You're not listening for resize events.  My snippet has $(document).resize(checkResize).  You'll need something similar in your code.